# Single-Write-Connection DB Access - Availability

Tags: database-design, architecture

There are two interesting posts about it

http://ithare.com/ultimate-db-heresy-single-writing-db-connection-part-ii-gradual-scalability-all-the-way-from-no-scale-to-perfect-scale/

http://ithare.com/ultimate-db-heresy-single-db-connection-part-i-performance-part-ii-scalability-to-follow

It implies the data access layer cannot be embedded into its clients (i.e. business layer). It has to be a shared layer with only one instance.

My question is how to make it high available while only one instance is deployed? Well we can create a new EC2 instance with same AMI, but how to consider availability from architecture perspective

Was wondering if there are patterns or frameworks that support failover, leader election, etc. At last Azure Fabric may be an option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how to make it high available while only one instance
>   is deployed?

I think those articles say about a single connection instance to a database server, not about a single instance of a database server itself.

You can transparently connect to something like [pgPool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [plProxy](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL/Proxy) which handles failover in some way. And there would be several DB servers behind it.